# How to find the limit $\lim _{n\to \infty}\left(1-\left(\frac{y}{n}\right)^n\right)^n?$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to find the limit ($y$ is a positive constant) $$\lim _{n\to \infty}\left(1-\left(\frac{y}{n}\right)^n\right)^n$$

Probably equal to $e^{-y}$. By squeeze theorem, it should be less than or equal to $e^{-y}$. Anyone has any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

Use that

$$\left(1-\left(\frac{y}{n}\right)^n\right)^n=e^{n\log\left(1-\left(\frac{y}{n}\right)^n\right)}$$

and

$$n\log\left(1-\left(\frac{y}{n}\right)^n\right)
=\frac{ny^n}{n^n}\cdot \frac{\log\left(1-\left(\frac{y}{n}\right)^n\right)}{\left(\frac{y}{n}\right)^n}$$

or as an alternative

$$\left(1-\left(\frac{y}{n}\right)^n\right)^n=\left[\left(1-\left(\frac{y}{n}\right)^n\right)^{\frac1{\left(\frac{y}{n}\right)^n}}\right]^{\frac{ny^n}{n^n}}$$